# Is there a no storyboard option in XCode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am creating a Single View Application in iOS 5.1.1.  When I select single view option I no longer see the option to NOT use a storyboard:

[image]

Instead, my screen looks like this:

[image]

This is a nuisance because I have to:

- Delete the storyboard
- Remove the storyboard from the project build options
- Add a UIViewController and hook it into the AppDelegate

Is there a way to not use storyboards?  I just want a xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to do that. Create an empty project without storyboard and views and add one xib. But IMO when you're working on single application view you should use a Storyboard, it has many advantages instead of xib file. Why you need a xib instead of storyboard?

Comment: I'm doing game development.  I don't think I need storyboards.

Comment: So as I said, creating an empty application and new view controller with a xib is faster than what you're doing now.